# How to change values in IQueryable field in C# with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, iqueryable

I have a variable that stores a select projection from a repository. The field in this variable are `month` and `value`. In a special case I would like to have all the `value` data divided by 100, WITHOUT changing the name of the variable and by keeping the information in the month field.

I know the procedure with LINQ to store permanently the items in the repository by using `InsertonSubmit()` but I do NOT want to store the records but just to have them modified in the context of my application. Hereby I add some code. I know it is wrong but it is just to give a better idea of what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance.

```
var lmonthlyTargetvalue = lmonthlyReport
                           .Select(m => new { m.Monthly_TargetValue, m.Month });

//If the Target value is percentual it is divided by 100
if (!Absolute)
{
  foreach (var monthRecord in lmonthlyTargetvalue)
  {
    var lvalue = lmonthlyTargetvalue.
             Where(m => m.Month == monthRecord.Month).
              Select(m => m.Monthly_TargetValue).First();
        lvalue = lvalue / 100;
      }
}
```

UPDATE:

Finally I have been  able to do it thanks to your contributions.  Here I list the solution:

```
    var lmonthlyTargetvalue = lmonthlyReport.Select(m => new
{
    Monthly_TargetValue = absolute ? m.Monthly_TargetValue : m.Monthly_TargetValue  / 100,
    m.Month
});
```

Comment: Where is the Absolute coming from?

Comment: It is just a flag. It belongs to another object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this (as a query expression);

```
var lmonthlyTargetvalue = from m in lmonthlyReport
             let Monthly_TargetValue = absolute ? m.Monthly_TargetValue : m.Monthly_TargetValue / 100
             select new { Monthly_TargetValue , m.Month };
```

That might even be slight overkill for this, as it introduces an extra anonymous type behind the scenes. This is OK too;

```
var lmonthlyTargetvalue = lmonthlyReport.Select(m => new
{
    Monthly_TargetValue = absolute ? m.Monthly_TargetValue : m.Monthly_TargetValue  / 100,
    m.Month
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is syntactically incorrect, sorry

Comment: @Francesco: Why do you think that? It compiles and runs just fine, and it produces the same results as the code you posted in your update to the original question.

Comment: @Francesco: No problem, glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2):

this should work;

```
IQueryable<lmonthlyReport> lmonthlyTargetvalue = lmonthlyReport
                       .Select(m => new { m.Monthly_TargetValue, m.Month });

IList<lmonthlyReport> _temp = new List<lmonthlyReport>();

foreach(var item in lmonthlyTargetvalue){

  _temp.Add(new lmonthlyReport {

    Monthly_TargetValue = item.Monthly_TargetValue / 100,

    Month = item.Month

  });

}

return _temp.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: I guess you made it, although is a bit a "dirty" approach. Don't get me wrong, I really appreciated your help. Without knowing the contest around this is the best answer you could've given! Many thanks

Comment: @Francesco yeah, you are right but I don't see any alternatives here? can you see? you're welcome.

Comment: What's wrong with just encompassing the "absolute" logic into the anonymous type initialisation? See my answer for an example.

Comment: I guess the problem is that you cannot assign a variable which is already exisitng in a Select statement. Moreover if the "absolute" method belongs to another object it is not recognized by the anonymus type inizialization. These are just my guess upon compiler response. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Francesco: My answer doesn't assign to an existing variable though. If you look at the statement again, you'll see that "Monthly_TargetValue" is a property of a new anonymous type. It's not the same variable as m.Monthly_TargetValue, which is a property of your Monthly_Report object. It's only named the same because that was one of your requirements :)

Comment: @C.McAtackney: Sorry I changed a bit the code and now it works! Thanks very much!

Comment: that's sad :S My answer vote went to @C.McAtackney :S it's ok though. no broken feelings.

Comment: @Tugberk: I'm really sorry, your answer put me in the right path but I had to vote the one that provides the most complete and DRY solution. I wish there was a way to give some vote to you. Thanks anyway and sorry again

Comment: @Francesco don't worry. I am just joking around. I also support the DRY methods everytime. I just gave the answer on the fly. ***[but, you could still vote it uppp :))]*** kidding :) it's up to you:)

Comment: @Tugberk: I just gained the privilege to vote it up! Here you have ;-)

Comment: @Francesco ohh mann :) that's very sweet of you. thanks dude :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 //If the Target value is percentual it is divided by 100
if (!Absolute)
{
     lmonthlyReport.Select(m => new { m.Monthly_TargetValue, m.Month, dividedValue = m.Monthly_TargetValue/100 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is syntactically incorrect, sorry

Comment: Thanks but this way it creates another field "dividedValue". I need to keep the Monthly_TargetValue so in this way I avoid a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: Wait, you want to have TargetValue and dividedValue at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
var lmonthlyTargetvalue = 
    lmonthlyReport.Select(m => new 
    { 
         IsAbsolute(m.Monthly_TargetValue) ? m.Monthly_TargetValue : m.Monthly_TargetValue / 100, 
         m.Month 
    });
```

Where IsAbsolute is whatever function you use to check whether the target value is a percentage or not.

This will immediately project the correct value into your variable

Comment: Many thanks for your answer but it is syntactically incorrect. Of course I created a method IsAbsolute that returns a bool value. The compiler does not like it, sorry